# Add places to heatmap from Firebase with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I'm trying to do a simple task, but I'm new to javascript, firebase and google maps API. I just want to create a map (I think that a heatmap would be better) with the data points from my firebase database.

My fireabse table is the following:

[image]

I'm using a code from google dev website (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/firebase)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map {
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXX
             &libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <div id="map"></div>


    <script>

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
          zoom: 3,
          styles: [{
            featureType: 'poi',
            stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]  // Turn off points of interest.
          }, {
            featureType: 'transit.station',
            stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]  // Turn off bus stations, train stations, etc.
          }],
          disableDoubleClickZoom: true
        });
        }



      var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: [],
          map: map,
          radius: 16
        });

      var firebase = new Firebase("https://XXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/");
      var places = firebase.child('places');

      // Get that click from firebase.
      places.orderByChild('places').on('child_added',
       function(snapshot) {
         var newPosition = snapshot.val();
         var point = new google.maps.LatLng(newPosition.lat, newPosition.lng);
         heatmap.getData().push(point);
       }
      );




    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
>       at index.html:44

I've already looked for some answers here, but I couldn't load the library properly. Also, I don't know if the code is going to work. Could anyone suggest modifications on it? Really apreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You've got `async` and `defer` on the google map API script. That means it'll end up loading after your script, so the values you rely on are undefined. Try removing those attributes. Also, that's a very old version of Firebase (the google map docs are outdated), see the Firebase docs for the new init process. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start (you might want to update AFTER getting it to work though)

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the `asyc` and `defer` and now I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'HeatmapLayer' of undefined`

Comment: The only place I see `HeatmapLayer` in your code is, uh, near the bottom (no line numbers, dammit stackoverflow). I'm not sure exactly how the Google Maps API is supposed to be used, you'll need to reference the documentation.

Comment: Move the code that creates the heatmap into the `initMap` function.

Comment: Tried that but no success : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure it out the problems.

For some reason the line below wasn't working.

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I've replaced for the line below and added it at the beginning of my code.

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=visualization"></script>
```

Also, I've added the line below at the end of my code.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Find below the full script:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=visualization"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>


<script>

function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
      zoom: 3,
      styles: [{
        featureType: 'poi',
        stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]  // Turn off points of interest.
      }, {
        featureType: 'transit.station',
        stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]  // Turn off bus stations, train stations, etc.
      }],
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    });

var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: [],
    map: map,
    radius: 16
  });


var firebase = new Firebase("https://be-safe-anywhere.firebaseio.com/");
var places = firebase.child('places');

// Get that click from firebase.
places.orderByChild('places').on('child_added',
 function(snapshot) {
   var newPosition = snapshot.val();
   var point = new google.maps.LatLng(newPosition.lat, newPosition.lng);
   heatmap.getData().push(point);
 }
);    


}







google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);  
</script>
```